# Correct use of Bonus cards in Terra Mystica

Tags: terra-mystica

Does a player take a Bonus card as soon as they have passed their turn?

Page 7 of the rule book states "Three out of the nine Bonus cards award Victory points when you have completed all the actions you wish to take in the current Action phase (called passing)"

Does a player keep hold of every bonus card until they have completed their turn and passed? Does this mean that a player who passes may not have access to some Bonus cards because other players with turns remaining may still be holding them?

Comment: Note that any time a play passes, and is choosing a new bonus card, they will always have 3 to pick from, as the rest will be in the hands of other players.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One action you can take in Terra Mystica is ending your participation for the round.

To do this, you first select a new bonus card out of the ones remaining (taking any bonus gold that exists on that bonus card).

Then you apply End-of-Turn bonuses from your existing bonus card (as you mention - there are three bonus cards that may award victory points based on how many dwellings, etc. you own).

Now the round is officially over for you, and others may now select the bonus card you just put back.

--

In other words - yes; a player takes a bonus card as soon as they end their participation in the round (and some won't be available, as other players will still have theirs).